# Finding the angle between vectors

Tags: vectors

What is the difference between

$\cos(\theta) = \frac{(v \cdot u) }{( \|v\| \|u\| )}$

and

$\cos(\theta) = \frac{|(v\cdot u)|}{( \|v\| \|u\| )}$

I noticed that my textbook uses simply the value of the dot product of vectors $v$ and $u$ for vectors with only $x$ and $y$ components but the absolute value of the dot product for vectors with $x, y$, and $z$ components. I would like to know why this is.

Comment: The sign tells you the orientation of $v$ with respect to $u$.

Comment: *I noticed that my textbook uses* -- Which textbook is this?

Answer (score 0):

Note that both $u$ and $v$ are vectors. Since the absolute value is the non-negative form of that value, the absence and addition of the modulus is related to direction of the vectors. For example, take $-u$ and $v$ (or $u$ and $-v$). From the diagram below, the vectors $v$ and $w$ are in different directions in the first quadrant. Changing the sign of $v$ would move it into the second quadrant.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$\vec v = a \hat i + b \hat j$
$\vec u = c \hat i + d \hat j$

Angle of $\vec v = \theta = \arctan \frac{b}{a}$
Angle of $\vec u = \phi = \arctan \frac{d}{c}$

Adjusting for quadrants as required ...
The angle between $\vec v$ and $\vec u$ = $\theta - \phi$

Answer (score 0):

Given vectors $v$ and $u$,

- $\theta=\cos^{-1}\frac{v \cdot u }{ \|v\| \|u\| }$ is the angle between $v$ and $u$; while
- $\mu=\cos^{-1}\frac{|v \cdot u |}{ \|v\| \|u\| }$ is the non-obtuse angle between $v$ and $u$.

We always have $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ and $\mu\in[0,\pi/2]$.

If $\theta\in[0,\pi/2]$, then $\mu=\theta$.

If $\theta\in(\pi/2,\pi]$, then $\mu=\pi-\theta$.

---

Example 1: $\beta=\cos^{-1}\frac{\mathbf c \cdot \mathbf d }{ \|\mathbf c\| \|\mathbf d\| }$ is the angle between $\mathbf c$ and $\mathbf d$, while $\alpha=\cos^{-1}\frac{|\mathbf c \cdot \mathbf d |}{ \|\mathbf c\| \|\mathbf d\| }$ is the non-obtuse angle between $\mathbf c$ and $\mathbf d$.

[image]

Example 2: $\gamma=\cos^{-1}\frac{\mathbf e \cdot \mathbf f }{ \|\mathbf e\| \|\mathbf f\| }=\cos^{-1}\frac{|\mathbf e \cdot \mathbf f |}{ \|\mathbf e\| \|\mathbf f\| }$ is both the angle and the non-obtuse angle between $\mathbf e$ and $\mathbf f$.

[image]

---

> I noticed that my textbook uses simply the value of the dot product of vectors $v$ and $u$ for vectors with only $x$ and $y$ components but the absolute value of the dot product for vectors with $x, y$, and $z$ components. I would like to know why this is.

This is strange and I'm not sure why this would be. But not knowing which textbook this is and what you're referring to, I can't answer this.